# PhoneStateListener and service

Tags: android

i have a phonestatelistener:
how can i start service here?
i tried:

```
startService(new Intent(this, TTS.class));
```

how ever it doent work for me

```
private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

          @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

           try {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                //i want to start service
                startService(new Intent(this, TTS.class));
```

Comment: Lock at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361117/how-to-start-phonestatelistener-programmatically

Comment: i get this error when i write the line that i wrote above: "The constructor Intent(new PhoneStateListener(){}, Class<HandsFree.TTS>) is undefined" , @ Pasha, i didnt understand from your link what should i do inorder to start the service?

Comment: pls check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948706/phonestatelistener-memory-leak-android) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948706/phonestatelistener-memory-leak-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
startService(new Intent(this, TTS.class));
```

the first parameter of `new Intent()` must be a `Context`. Usually you call this from a `Service` or from an `Activity`, both of which extend `Context`.

In your case, your `this` parameter is the class `PhoneStateListener` which does not extend `Context`. I assume that this is a private inner class. You need to specify the outer class like this:

```
startService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, TTS.class));
```

If your outer class is an activity, then `MyActivity` should be the name of the activity. If the outer class is a service, then `MyActivity` should be the name of the service.